# High CPU usage Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Process

Tags: spservices, space-usage

Configuration of sytem 
RAM : 12GB

I don't understand why server consume too much memory in two particular process

1. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
2. SharePoint Search Component

[image]

**Tried Solution**:
Search service configure in **"reduce"** level [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082188/sharepoint-search-component-has-multiple-process-and-use-lots-memory)

Comment: Hi Amit, Could you provide us with more information about the SharePoint Farm? What version, how many servers are there and how are the Service Applications spread over the servers? It is possible one server has too many service applications assigned.

Comment: It's pleasure, there is single server in single farm which is SharePoint enterprise version, more importantly all service in one farm especially search service consume more memory , should I stop search service in period of time? and  what's the reason behind "Microsoft SharePoint foundation" service high consumption? @TempaC

Answer (score 3):

Search is a pretty resource intensive component of a SharePoint farm.  If the system has a lot of content to process/crawl and this impacting your daily operations then you should check that continuous crawling is disabled and then schedule your crawling for off hours.

It sounds a bit like you may not have enough RAM to begin with.  12 GB seems like a fair amount but if you consider that the Microsoft recommendation is 24 GB for a single server farm that has all the services enabled then 12 GB may not be enough depending on what services you are running.

See this section here: [Hardware Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#hwforwebserver)

Comment: any clues to schedule my crawl in off hours ? @Erik

Comment: In Central Administration, find your Search Service Application and then examine each Content Source you have.  Look at the Crawl Schedules to determine whether you have Continuous Crawls enabled, and to change the frequency and schedule of your Incremental and Full crawls.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to manager memory on standalone development machine.
Although, it is not recommended but you can "Stop SharePoint search host controller" service only on development machine temporarily to proceed with development.
My best experience is to have MIN-24GB RAM on development machine.

### On Tier, topology must have a separate Index server with minimum 16GB RAM.

Otherwise, you can do the following:
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService –PerformanceLevel "PartlyReduced"
Here is Performance Level Explanation:
•   Reduced: Total number of threads = number of processors, Max Threads/host = number of processors
•   Partly Reduced: Total number of threads = 4 times the number of processors , Max Threads, host = 16 times the number of processors
•   Maximum: Total number of threads = 4 times the number of processors , Max Threads, host = 16 times the number of processors (threads are created at HIGH priority)
Let setting take effects, run IISReset /noforce command or restart the Search Service in Central Admin